# Saving program shared data in Exchange Public Folder

Tags: com, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, mapi

I have a question reffering to Public Folders on Exchange Server.

I have an application (Outlook Com Addin) that need to share settings amonge every Exchange User that have access to Public Folders.

I was thinking about storing settings in MAPI assotiated message (hidden MAPI message). Wirting\Reading data from this message works fine, but I don't have good place to save this item.

I am looking from some sort of global folder or root folder that every user have. I tried All Public Folders folder, but noone can store any item there. I was also thinking about NON_IPM_SUBTREE but I am not sure which folder can be used to write there something.

Maybe someone faced this problem already and have some thoughts about this it?

And to make things clear. I am using Extended MAPI, but if you know any solution that involves Outlook API, I would be interested in that too.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

There are no predefined PF folders. Most installations will have "Outlook Security Settings", but that is about it.
There is also a set of hidden folders where Outlook stores f/b info.

Keep in mind that PF is optional as of Exchange 2007. Exchange 2010 does not install PF store by default.

Comment: I am aware that Public Folders are not alway available, but my Outlook Addin works only on Public Folders. SO if there are no PF than user cannot use Addin. Also can you tell me is it safe to add my data into SHEDULE\FREE BUSY folder?